# Generate an alert when deleting a line on excel

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to generate an alert when deleting a line on Excel?

Do I have to use some coding langage like VBA to do so or can I do it just with Excel?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to *prevent* a line from being deleted?

Comment: Yes I want to generate an alert each time someone tries to delete a line which isn't duplicated on the Excel .

Comment: You can do this on sheet by having an array formula that has at least one of its cells in the row that you don't want to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your goal seems to be preventing row deletion, not just popping up a warning message:

1. Select the entire row(s) you want protected
2. Right click, then select `Format Cells`
3. Go to the `Protection` tab and ensure `Locked` is checked
4. On the Ribbon, select `Review`, then `Protect Sheet`
5. Check the box next to `Delete Rows`
6. Provide a password & click OK

If you're actually after a warning message, then this won't do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've tried this before and it wasn't successful because there is a problem with the excel-vba  on the sheet.

Comment: My guess is that your VBA is trying to update protected cells. If that's the case, you can unprotect the sheet with VBA, make your changes, then reprotect it. Don't know if that helps...